# change the format of time and date in R

Tags: r, sentiment-analysis

I am working on twitter data by useing R and I have column for date and time like this "10/19/2018 23:00" , "10/19/2018 23:01", "10/19/2018 23:02" ,"10/19/2018 19:45".
I want  to change the format to be without date and also the time be without minute for example any time on 23 hour I need it to be on 23 only without minute.
this is an example of the column:

```
created
10/19/2018 23:29
10/19/2018 23:29
10/19/2018 23:29
10/19/2018 23:29
10/19/2018 23:29
10/19/2018 23:29
10/19/2018 23:29
10/19/2018 23:29
10/19/2018 23:29
10/19/2018 23:29
10/19/2018 23:29
10/19/2018 23:29
10/19/2018 23:29
10/19/2018 23:29
10/19/2018 23:29
10/19/2018 23:29
10/19/2018 23:29
10/19/2018 23:29
10/19/2018 23:29
10/19/2018 23:29
10/19/2018 23:29
10/19/2018 23:29
10/19/2018 23:29
10/19/2018 23:29
10/19/2018 23:29
10/19/2018 23:29
10/19/2018 23:29
10/19/2018 23:29
10/19/2018 23:29
10/19/2018 23:29
10/19/2018 23:29
10/19/2018 23:29
10/19/2018 23:29
10/19/2018 23:29
10/19/2018 23:29
10/19/2018 23:29
10/19/2018 23:29
10/19/2018 23:29
10/19/2018 23:29
10/19/2018 23:29
10/19/2018 23:29
10/19/2018 23:29
10/19/2018 23:29
10/19/2018 23:29
10/19/2018 23:29
10/19/2018 23:29
10/19/2018 23:29
10/19/2018 23:29
10/19/2018 23:29
10/19/2018 23:29
10/19/2018 23:29
10/19/2018 23:29
10/19/2018 23:29
10/19/2018 23:29
10/19/2018 23:29
10/19/2018 23:29
10/19/2018 23:29
10/19/2018 23:29
10/19/2018 23:29
10/19/2018 23:29
10/19/2018 23:29
10/19/2018 23:29
10/19/2018 23:29
10/19/2018 23:29
10/19/2018 23:29
10/19/2018 23:29
10/19/2018 23:29
10/19/2018 23:29
10/19/2018 23:29
10/19/2018 23:29
10/19/2018 23:29
10/19/2018 23:29
10/19/2018 23:29
10/19/2018 23:29
10/19/2018 23:29
10/19/2018 23:29
10/19/2018 23:29
10/19/2018 23:29
10/19/2018 23:29
10/19/2018 23:29
10/19/2018 23:29
10/19/2018 23:29
10/19/2018 23:29
10/19/2018 23:29
10/19/2018 23:29
10/19/2018 23:29
10/19/2018 23:29
10/19/2018 23:29
10/19/2018 23:29
10/19/2018 23:28
10/19/2018 23:28
10/19/2018 23:28
10/19/2018 23:28
10/19/2018 23:28
10/19/2018 23:28
10/19/2018 23:28
10/19/2018 23:28
10/19/2018 23:28
10/19/2018 23:28
10/19/2018 23:28
10/19/2018 23:28
10/19/2018 23:28
10/19/2018 23:28
10/19/2018 23:28
10/19/2018 23:28
10/19/2018 23:28
10/19/2018 23:28
10/19/2018 23:28
10/19/2018 23:28
10/19/2018 23:28
10/19/2018 23:28
10/19/2018 23:28
10/19/2018 23:28
10/19/2018 23:28
10/19/2018 23:28
10/19/2018 23:28
10/19/2018 23:28
10/19/2018 23:28
10/19/2018 23:28
10/19/2018 23:28
10/19/2018 23:28
10/19/2018 23:28
10/19/2018 23:28
10/19/2018 23:28
10/19/2018 23:28
10/19/2018 23:28
10/19/2018 23:28
10/19/2018 23:28
10/19/2018 23:28
10/19/2018 23:28
10/19/2018 23:28
10/19/2018 23:28
10/19/2018 23:28
10/19/2018 23:28
10/19/2018 23:28
10/19/2018 23:28
10/19/2018 23:28
10/19/2018 23:28
10/19/2018 23:28
10/19/2018 23:28
10/19/2018 23:28
10/19/2018 23:28
10/19/2018 23:28
10/19/2018 23:28
10/19/2018 23:28
10/19/2018 23:28
10/19/2018 23:28
10/19/2018 23:28
10/19/2018 23:28
10/19/2018 23:28
10/19/2018 23:28
10/19/2018 15:32
10/19/2018 15:32
10/19/2018 15:32
10/19/2018 15:32
10/19/2018 15:32
10/19/2018 15:32
10/19/2018 15:32
10/19/2018 15:32
```

and I need it to be like this 
        15:00
        23:00
        16:00

hope you understand me 
can you help me to do it and thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
x<-
c("10/19/2018 23:29", "10/19/2018 23:29", "10/19/2018 23:29", "10/19/2018 23:29")

paste0(unlist(regmatches(x, gregexpr("(?<=\\s)\\d{2}(?=:\\d{2})", x, perl = T))), ":00")
```

---

```
#[1] "23:00" "23:00" "23:00" "23:00"
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `sub`

```
sub('.*\\s(.{2}).*', '\\1:00', df1$created)
#[1] "23:00" "23:00" "23:00" "23:00"
```

---

Or convert to a `DateTime` class and then extract the components with `format`

```
format(as.POSIXct(df1$created, format = "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M"), "%H:00")
#[1] "23:00" "23:00" "23:00" "23:00"
```

#### data

```
df1 <- data.frame(created = c('10/19/2018 23:29',
  '10/19/2018 23:29', '10/19/2018 23:29', 
  '10/19/2018 23:29'), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: yes thank you, first one is worked but it's removed the date only I need to remove the minute also. I need the hour only

Comment: If you check the output, you can see that it is working fine